# issues while developing for PHILIPS HUE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1, philips-hue

I am making an application using [meethue api for apple](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/apple-api-guide).

I don't have any device (bridge) to check the output. How can I proceed my development using my simulator.

Is their any way from which I can test or know how my app is working without having bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a hue emulator.

For example, the [Hue-emulator by SteveyO](http://steveyo.github.io/Hue-Emulator/) is a simple .jar file which can be run using the command:

```
java -jar HueEmulator-v0.2.jar
```

After this, the following request can be used to check whether the emulator is running:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/newdeveloper
```

The full bridge config should be returned.

Comment: i am developing for iPhone.. can i still use it ?

Comment: Yes. It is mentioned in the Introduction of the hue Apple SDK... "To develop for Hue you require the Philips Hue Personal Wireless Lighting System or a suitable hue Emulator."

Comment: Thanx @ZeMoon ........ please tell me one one more thing i have to give ip address to the emulator or just the port number..

Comment: Read the API and emulator guide for all this information.

Comment: i need your help... i have run the emulator and trying to connect to the emulator but i am not getting any match...

Comment: my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387614/how-to-switch-on-and-off-philps-hue-lights

Answer (score 0):

Dalvik,
If you know how to write an app for Apple, you know how to run java jar on Apple's product.
Writing Hue app you have to know Hue API , giving answers to all your questions.

Hue API is easy.
$.json  Hue API calls are easy (PUT, GET, SET ...)

Dialog + ncurses + curl + CLI + bash  is easy

Writing an app for Apple is not easy so I write Hue API apps for Android and Windows  - Hue Ambilight Smart TV for Android, Windows

Comment: Ya i know that HUE have an easy API.But there is issues with it like. I have to manualy enter the ip address and the user name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670558/cant-change-the-username-of-philips-hue please elp

Comment: Dalvik, all you need to set up manually is port since IP is preset to localhost (port is preset to :8000 I chan ge to :80 to get . Just run Hue Emulator for Windows (jar file on your apple's device) and open http://localhost:8000 (or :80)/api/newdeveloper in your preferred web browser to access Hue Emulator by Steve.