# how to switch on and off PHILPS HUE lights

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, philips-hue

I am using [HUE-Emulator](http://steveyo.github.io/Hue-Emulator/) to view the changes.Emulator is running on `port 80`.

Currently I am only able to view the details using browser.(API calls)

Now I want to switch off and switch on the lights using my app.But my code doesn't detect the bridge. I am not using any physical device. I am running my app in simulator.

> Code I am using to find Bridges

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.phHueSDK = [[PHHueSDK alloc] init];

[self.phHueSDK enableLogging:YES];

// Call startUpSDK which will initialize the SDK
[self.phHueSDK startUpSDK];

self.bridgeSearch = [[PHBridgeSearching alloc] initWithUpnpSearch:YES andPortalSearch:YES];

// Start search for bridges
[self.bridgeSearch startSearchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *bridgesFound) {

    NSLog(@"sadsdsa %@",bridgesFound);   //Logs Null
}];

 }
```

Links to Screen shots of my emulator to show everything works fine.

[Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/qnZfcPZb)

Config I am getting:

http://pastebin.com/wzreYSng

Comment: Please update the question with the config you get after opening `http://localhost:8000/api/newdeveloper`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs from the Hue Emulator, you will notice that BridgeSearch will work only when the bridge emulator is running on port 80.

The relevant part from the config you posted is as follows:

```
"config":{  
      "portalservices":false,
      "gateway":"192.168.2.1",
      "mac":"00:00:88:00:bb:ee",
      "swversion":1005215,
      "linkbutton":false,
      "ipaddress":"192.168.2.13:8000",
      "proxyport":0,
      "swupdate":{  
         "text":"",
         "notify":false,
         "updatestate":0,
         "url":""
      }
```

You can directly connect to the bridge emulator using the code:

```
[self.phHueSDK setBridgeToUseWithIpAddress:@"192.168.2.13:8000" macAddress:@"00:00:88:00:bb:ee"];
```

I would suggest you download the [sample iOS application](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDK-iOS-OSX/tree/master/QuickStartApp_iOS) provided by PhilipsHue and try it out.

Comment: I tried this also ... after this when i search for bridge using PHBridgeSearching i am getting null dictionary

Comment: I also used the sample app..the sample app is not able to find the bridge

Comment: Try changing the port number on the emulator application to 80.

Comment: Can you directly connect to the bridge using the setBridgeToUse method as specified in the answer?

Comment: wiil i have to add Puhlink notification also ?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71170/ios-magicians   lets discuss it here i have a lot to ask

Comment: please Help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670558/cant-change-the-username-of-philips-hue